# loops in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
import java.util.Random;
public class arrayClass
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [][] array = new int [5][5];
        Random gen = new Random();

        for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
        {
            array[x][2]= gen.nextInt(15) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code is brief but it might be enough for you to understand

Okay so my goal right now is to put random numbers into each cell without "brute forcing" it(so using loops). I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate two variables in a `for` loop. Also, how could I make it so that the first row will increase one cell when the cells within the row is done in a loop (in this case cell 0 through 4 in one row)

And is there a way to output a specific range of cells?

thanks and sorry I know this might be pretty confusing

Comment: How is a loop not brute forcing?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a nested loop? Why?

Comment: Brute forcing as in array [0][0]= ..... array [0][1] = .... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really should use a double for loop here:

```
for (int x=0; x < array.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < array[x].length; ++y) {
        array[x][y]= gen.nextInt(15) + 1;
    }
}
```

You could use a single for loop to populate the 2D array, but it would require an external loop counter, and in the end would be functionally similar to a double loop.

Comment: Agree, but I would code `for (int y=0; y < array[x].length; ++y)`, since not all rows may be the same length. Free safety, code char count same.

Comment: Okay I understand now Thank you for your answer!